# Why might describing Amazon EC2 instances yield no result?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to retrieve all the instances running in my AWS account (say instance id, etc). I use the following code. I am not able to print the instance ids. When I debug, I am just getting null values. But I have three instances running on AWS. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

```
 DescribeInstancesResult result = ec2.describeInstances();

 List<Reservation> reservations = result.getReservations();

 for (Reservation reservation : reservations) {
      List<Instance> instances = reservation.getInstances();

      for (Instance instance : instances) {
           System.out.println(instance.getInstanceId());
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause for issues like this is a missing region specification when initializing the client, see section *To create and initialize an Amazon EC2 client* within [Create an Amazon EC2 Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/init-ec2-client.html) for details:

Specifically, step 2 only creates an EC2 client without specifying the region explicitly:

> 2) Use the AWSCredentials object to create a new AmazonEC2Client instance, as follows:
>
> ```
> amazonEC2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
> ```

This yields a client talking to `us-east-1` - surprisingly, the [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) and the [AWS Management Console](https://aws.amazon.com/console/) use different defaults even as outlined in step 3, which also shows how to specify a different endpoint:

> 3) By default, the service endpoint is ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. To specify a different endpoint, use the setEndpoint method. For example:
>
> ```
> amazonEC2Client.setEndpoint("ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com");
> ```
>
> **The AWS SDK for Java uses US East (N. Virginia) as the default region**
>   if you do not specify a region in your code. **However, the AWS
>   Management Console uses US West (Oregon) as its default.** Therefore,
>   when using the AWS Management Console in conjunction with your
>   development, be sure to specify the same region in both your code and
>   the console. *[emphasis mine]*

The differing defaults are easy to trip over, and the respective default in the AWS Management Console has in fact changed over time - as so often in software development, I recommend to always be explicit about this in your code to avoid such subtle error sources.

Comment: Spot on! Works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you! I just wasted an embarrassing amount time wondering why I was getting no results, and it turned out I had forgotten to set the region.